# Установка node.js в PhpStorm. Не активируется. В чём причина?

Tags: node.js, phpstorm, npm

Установил с оф.сайта node.js , прописал в консоли версию - 10.15.1

Далее пошёл в phpshtorm запускать. Интегрировал node.js, перехожу в раздел "Языки и фреймворки", "Node.js" и там указываю путь к node.exe. Нажимаю на кнопку "Enable" и всё... не активируется. В чём проблема может быть?

Лог ошибки:

> E:\NodeJs\node.exe E:\NodeJs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js -g
>   uninstall npm
>
> Standard error: npm ERR! path E:\NodeJs\npx.cmd npm ERR! code EEXIST
>   npm ERR! Refusing to delete E:\NodeJs\npx.cmd: is outside
>   E:\NodeJs\node_modules\npm and not a link npm ERR! File exists:
>   E:\NodeJs\npx.cmd npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 0):

[Старая проблема](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/300#issuecomment-446189422), насколько я могу [судить](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/389#issuecomment-419090482).

Создайте `.bat` в директории ноды с таким содержанием и запустите:

```
pushd %ProgramFiles%\nodejs
del npm npm.cmd
move node_modules\npm node_modules\npm2
call node node_modules\npm2\bin\npm-cli.js i npm@latest -g
rmdir /S /Q node_modules\npm2
popd
pause
```

А лучше вручную по одной эти команды выполняйте в директории ноды, от греха подальше.

Comment: Просто создать в установленной директории node.js файл 1.bat и прописать там "pushd %ProgramFiles%\nodejs
del npm npm.cmd
move node_modules\npm node_modules\npm2
call node node_modules\npm2\bin\npm-cli.js i npm@latest -g
rmdir /S /Q node_modules\npm2
popd
pause" ? После чего запустить файл и всё?

Comment: @user239511 да, так. Или открыть cmd, переместиться в директорию, где установлена нода и выполнить эти команды вручную по очереди.

Comment: Я понял. Сейчас попробую. Единственное, первая строчка pushd %ProgramFiles%\nodejs , верна ли будет в моём случае, если у меня node.js установлен на диске E?

Comment: @user239511 пути подкорректируйте под те, что у вас.

Comment: @Suvitrus , спасибо! Получается так: `pushd E:\NodeJs\node
del npm npm.cmd
move node_modules\npm node_modules\npm2
call node node_modules\npm2\bin\npm-cli.js i npm@latest -g
rmdir /S /Q node_modules\npm2
popd
pause` . Но у меня нет такой папке в папке node_modules папки npm2. Только такие: http://images.vfl.ru/ii/1549884823/f33d3d1a/25346826.png
Какую нужно указать? Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: @user239511 не уверен, т.к. такой проблемы не было. Лучше уточнить по ссылкам, что я привёл.

Comment: Что только не перепробовал... И переустанавливал библиотеку, и 11 версию установил... Результат: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" --inspect=43236 --debug-brk C:\OSPanel\domains\java.com\index.js
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:43236/57463d11-0f07-4660-b788-0568c4b2a038
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
(node:7208) [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: `node --inspect --debug-brk` is deprecated. Please use `node --inspect-brk` instead.
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect... Что ему не нравится?